# I m assigned a project to create karaoke system on matlab. But im a noob in Audio processing and i don't know to approach this problem. Please help

Tags: matlab, fft, audio

Im simulating a karaoke system. I m giving a mono channel audio as input and i should get instrumental component of audio as output(all vocal component should be removed from audio).

i tried two approaches but none of them worked

```
[y,fs]=wavread('bb.wav');
left=y(:,1);
right=y(:,2);
wavplay(left-right,fs);
```

2nd

```
[y, fs] = wavread('Song.wav');
left = y(:,1);
right = y(:,2);
fftL = fft(left);
fftR = fft(right);

for i = 1:683550 %in my example 683550
dif = fftL(i,1) / fftR(i,1);
dif = abs(dif);
if (dif > 0.7 & dif < 1.5)
fftL(i,1) = 0;
fftR(i,1) = 0;
 end;
end;

leftOut = ifft(fftL);
rightOut = ifft(fftR);
yOut(:,1) = leftOut;
yOut(:,2) = rightOut;

wavwrite(yOut, fs, 'tmp.wav');
```

Comment: I am not an audio person, but I know enough about it to say that this is a very difficult problem.  And, no offense, given your attempted solutions this is, in my opinion, too tough a problem for you right now.

Comment: it **is** real hard.  i know of some methods that would subtract left from right, with the assumption that the voice was mixed in the middle.  a better method involved some sorta pitch detector and a variable comb filter tuned to the pitch that would knock out the fundamental and harmonics.  still not so good if the voice gets a little buried by the instruments.  dunno what else i would do for this.

Comment: Well this is working but result is not quite satisfactory
[y,fs]=audioread('ab.mp3'); 
        a=y(:,1);
        b=y(:,2);
       A=fft(a);
       B=fft(b);
       C=(-1)*B;
       D=A+C;
       d=ifft(D); 
       c=d/2;

Comment: The last comment proposes to subtract the right channel from the left channel. That is basically what @robertbristow-johnson suggested. Due to the linearity of the discrete Fourier transformation there is no benefit in performing the computation in the frequency-domain.